# how to get out of bullet mode in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the best practice for leaving bullets mode in Word and going back to normal text.  Is there a shortcut?  I prefer not to have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hit enter! :)  That will move you to the next line and put you back in normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Normal style. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Source [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938)